# How To Target A Defined Range Of An Array

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, dom

My script below will grab an entire list of links from a specific URL to use for my dom scraper. But some of the lists can get into the 1000s, so I want to be able to manually set which links to actually grab. Like if I entered to start at link 50 and end at link 100 in the list. How would I do that?

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <label>Url to scrape: </label>
    <input type="text" name="url_scrape" id="url-scrape" />
    <input type="submit" value=" Scrape now " />
    <br />

    <input type="hidden" name="scrape" value="yes" />
    <br />

</form>
<br />
<br />
<?php

if( $_POST['scrape'] != 'yes' )
    return;



include('simple_html_dom.php');

function strim( $input ){

    $st = explode( '$', $input );

    return (float)str_replace( array(' ',','),array('',''), $st[1] );

}

$url_scrape = $_POST['url_scrape']; 

if( $url_scrape == '' )
    return; 



$BrowsebyLetter = file_get_html( $url_scrape );

$links = $BrowsebyLetter->find('.Results a');


?>
<h1 id="patient">Please be patient while scraping data</h1>

<div id="scrape-progress">
    <div id="scrape-progress-ctx">0%</div>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<div id="progress-txt"></div>
<br />
<br />
<button id="retry" onclick="iframe.src = ">Retry if not continue</button>
<iframe src="" id="cacheLoad"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var total = <?php echo count($links); ?>;
    var ctx = document.getElementById('scrape-progress-ctx');
    var iframe = document.getElementById('cacheLoad');
    var prx = document.getElementById('progress-txt');
    var pt = document.getElementById('patient');
    var retry = document.getElementById('retry');
    var currentLink = '';
    var links = [
<?php
    foreach( $links as $link ){

        echo "'".$link->href."',";

    }
?>'Complete scrape <?php echo count($links); ?> links'  ];
    function progress( cur ){
        ctx.style.width = Math.ceil((cur/total)*100)+'%';
        ctx.innerHTML = Math.ceil((cur/total)*100)+'%';
    };
    function exe( i ){
        progress( i );
        if( links[i] != 'Complete <?php echo count($links); ?> links' )
        {
            currentLink = window.location+'&target='+links[i].split('Job=')[1]+'&cou='+(i+1);
            iframe.src = currentLink;
        };  
        if( i==total ){
            pt.innerHTML = 'Successful';
            pt.style.color = 'green';
            retry.style.display = 'none';
            alert('Scrape process is complete');
        };  
        prx.innerHTML = '<strong>Status: </strong>'+ links[i];
    };
    exe( 0 );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to where ever your loop is:

```
    var links = [
<?php
    $a = 0;
    foreach( $links as $link ){
        $a++;
        if(($a > 50) && ($a < 100)){
            echo "'".$link->href."',";
        }
    }
?>
```

It will check if the link is between 50 and 100 and if it is it'll print it out. Hope I helped :)